# Any cheap SIM with just data plan in Majorca, Spain?

Tags: cellphones, spain

I was wondering if there is a cheap SIM + data plan from a provider I can get
in Majorca - Spain. Not interested in calls, only data preferably. Let's say
2GB for a week or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you define as 'cheap,' but I read up that Three provides the cheapest SIM plans for data overseas.

After visiting several websites and then chatting with a Three chat operator, [I found this](http://www.three.co.uk/Store/SIM/Plans_for_phones#sim-options-heading)

You'll probably want to select 1 month, and then look down the list for exactly how much data you want.

12gb is from £20 and Unlimited data is from £26 for one month, which is a pretty good deal in my opinion.

You'll need an unlocked 3g or 4g phone to use the sim